# How to listen an MailItem event in Mail Add-in?

Tags: outlook, office365-apps, office365api, apps-for-office, outlook-web-addins

I want to detect an event in Mail Add-in. In Outlook, thick/desktop version, we can detect the mail event, such as `MailItem.Send` and `MailItem.AttachmentAdd.`

Is it possible to listen to these events in Outlook online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there are almost no events of any kind in the Mailbox API, other than asynchronous callbacks that are only fired when you initiate them.  There is nothing that I'm aware of that can be used to detect item send or attachment modification events.

The closest option is to use the Outlook Notifications REST API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/notify-rest-operations), but these are more suitable to monitoring item/folder level changes.  Perhaps you can hook into a notification for the Sent Items folder to approximate a MailItem.Send operation, or watch changes to a draft item to detect a newly added attachment.

Comment: Yes, this could be an option. Thank you, @EricLegault.
Though, a workaround is needed to get my job done. The notification would only provide an estimation/approximation.

Is Microsoft planning to fill this gap? Or, they are not planning to support these events anymore?

Answer (score 0):

nop. you can't do this. Office Apps can't interact with buttons or actions on the client apps such as: Outlook.

Comment: It looks so. This could make my apps dormant.
I have been looking for any similar workaround to have it done.